# restart app working fine on android but not on windows flutter app

Tags: windows, flutter, flutter-windows

I am unable to find that how to restart windows app of flutter. I have used flutter package "rebirth" from pub.dev but it gives black screen and did not restart.[image: black screen image]

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
 final currentScript = Platform.script.toFilePath();

                        // Get the path to the Dart executable
                        final dartExecutable = Platform.executable;

                        // Execute the Dart executable with the current script's path
                        Process.start(dartExecutable, [currentScript]).then((Process process) {
                          // Close the current process
                          exit(0);
                        });
```